# laravel 4.1 validate url input

Tags: php, laravel

Okay after get almost every thing work in my code

and its pretty Good

i need help about how to validate the user url Input

and if he did insert a non Url how to foreword it to 404 page

and here is my Route file

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return  View::make('hello');    
}); 

Route::post('/', function()
{
$url = Input::get('url');
$record = Url::where('urls', '=', $url)->first();
if ($record) {
    return View::make('result')
    ->with('shortend', $record->shortend);
}

function get_uniqe_short_url()
{

    $shortend = base_convert(rand(1000,99999), 10, 36);
    if (Url::where('shortend', '=' ,$shortend)->first() ){
        get_uniqe_short_url();
    }
    return $shortend;
}
$shortend = get_uniqe_short_url();

// otherwise add new row and return shortned url 
 $row = new URl;
    $row->urls = $url;
    $row->shortend = $shortend;
    $row->save();

 // create a results view and present the short url to the usr 

 if ($row){
    return View::make('result')->with('shortend',$shortend);
 } 
});


Route::get('{shortend}', function($shortend) 
    {
     // query the DB For the row with that short url 
        $row = Url::where('shortend', '=', $shortend)->first();
     // if not found redirect to home page 
        if (is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');
     // else grab the url and redirect 
        return Redirect::to($row->urls);

    });
```

forgive me for my many questions but i am totally new to laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as a tip, you have logic like this in your routes.php.  A URL router is meant to take HTTP requests and "route" them to the correct controllers and methods.  See [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) to get started with controllers.

I am never a fan of "redirecting to a 404 page", instead I believe if a page isn't found it should display a 404 page there.  To do this with laravel, you can call `App::abort(404);` which will kill the application and return a 404 status to the browser.  You can take this a step further by "listening" to 404 errors and returning your own custom view:

```
App::missing(function()
{
    return View::make('errors/404');
});
```

Let me know if you need more help validating a URL, but I think you should start by restructuring your code by using controllers.  You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) for regular expressions to match URLs.  This is how you would use a regular expression in PHP:

```
if(!preg_match('/expression/', $url)) {
    App::abort(404);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help i will try it now and i will look in that url that you give to me and Thanks for helping me 
i will be back as soon as i done from testing the codes

Comment: Let me know how it goes and I can keep giving advice with problems.

Comment: Okay Sam 
Sorry for late replay but i had so much work in my office 
i will replay how its goes today

Comment: every thing is okay when i use the Controller
Now i am going to validate the Input of url

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for my late replay

Comment: will i have an error called unexpected T_IF

after typing this code 
     ' $validation = Validator::make(array(
  'url' => $url
  ), 
 array(
  'url' => 'required|url'
  ))
  if ( $validation->fails() ) 
  {
   return 'faild';

  } '

Comment: @Jone, it looks like you are missing a`;` after the `Validator::make()` statement and before your conditional.